# How to refresh current page after print window gets closed by user in asp.net?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

My Question is that :
" I have a grid view in which there are 6 columns , last 2 columns are EDIT and DETAILS . Now i also have a PRINT Button outside the DATAGRID , what i want is that , when a user clicks on that Print Button, My Last 2 columns Edit and Details got hide, then the print window appears , then user will click on either Print or Close that window (if he wish to) . after that print window closes or being closed by a user ,then, that 2 columns which i hide when the PRINT btn was clicked , now gets visible ... so far i have tried this code , i am successful only in hiding the last two columns and not showing them in print preview , BUT ! after that print window is closed , my hided columns are not showing again .... i have to reload my page manually by pressing CTRL + F5 ... how to achieve this task ? I want to show those columns again ... Please help me ... here's my code on PRINT BTN CLICK EVENT ....

```
protected void PrintBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            row.Cells[5].Visible = false;
            row.Cells[6].Visible = false;
            GridView1.Columns[5].Visible = false;
            GridView1.Columns[6].Visible = false;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
            sb.Append("function pageLoad(sender, args){");
            sb.Append("var prtContent = document.getElementById(\"divPrint\");");
            sb.Append("var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'letf=0,top=0,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');");
            sb.Append("WinPrint.document.write(prtContent.innerHTML);");
            sb.Append("WinPrint.document.close();");
            sb.Append("WinPrint.focus();");
            sb.Append("WinPrint.print();");
            sb.Append("WinPrint.close();}");

            sb.Append("</script>");
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, GetType(), "GridPrint", sb.ToString(), false);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS!

```
@media print
{
     .hideonprint{display:none;}   
}
@media screen
{
    .hideonprint{display:table-cell;}    
}
```

and set the class of the columns to **hideonprint**